# My button is not responding on Hover or Click in Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-ui

My button doesn't seem to be responsive. Although I have a EventSystem in my hierarchy. [image: It's the view of hierarchy and other]

This is my canvas inside the inspector, I have another Canvas in my scene called "Shop Canvas", but it has the same inspector values.
[image: Inspector view of canvas]

This is the EventSystem in the inspector.
[image: EventSystem In hierarchy]

Here is one of my buttons in the inspector.
[image: Button 1st Image in inspector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue of not being able to engage with a button. The reason being there was another UI component with ray cast enabled that did not allow inputs to reach the button.

For your case, I think it's the "The things...". Try disabling that and see if you can engage with the button again.

Comment: Oh thanks. I found another panel using raycast. I disable that and it's working. Thanks for  your help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I couldn't see button interactions in a scroll view. I eventually created a click event (which worked) to find the source of my problem. While it wasn't a Raycast problem, someone else might find this handy.

I set the color of the attached Image component to black and couldn't see the interaction states in the Button. Leave image.Color  as white/opaque but change button states if you want dark menus.

Side by side comparison:

[image: broken] [image: fixed]

Answer (score 0):

Just to help any more people who encounter this annoying issue.

Your `Button`, `EventSystem` and `Canvas` looks all good. There is another cause of the irresponsive UI buttons and I think it may be the most likely case for most people.

The issue occurs when you add a `camera` by yourself without tagging it as `MainCamera`. If you have no clue of tagging it, then it is very likely to be your cause.

**key point**: The `camera` you use with `standalone input module` must be tagged as `MainCamera`. Otherwise it won't recognise objects with no collider.